# plot the results from kmeans

Tags: python, visualization, k-means

I am trying to plot results from document (data source: twitter) clustering using python's sklearn. Below is 10-words of words belonging to each cluster:

```
donated     0.221646
cross       0.034354
red         0.033817
relief      0.030248
every       0.026620
victims     0.023084
efforts     0.021768
redcross    0.021427
wade        0.019810
million     0.018602
Name: 0, dtype: float64


victims      0.030352
help         0.026362
relief       0.020772
donate       0.020332
donations    0.012362
please       0.012352
want         0.012348
sandy        0.010720
new          0.010089
like         0.008957
Name: 1, dtype: float64


affected     0.179101
help         0.054969
please       0.027684
donate       0.026976
red          0.026417
people       0.026100
cross        0.025541
sandyhelp    0.025537
thoughts     0.023171
like         0.021116
Name: 2, dtype: float64
```

I am able to generate wordcloud by using [Amueller's wordcloud](https://github.com/amueller/word_cloud) .

I wanted to create a scatter plot of these clusters for an instance in above example, indicate the words are in one cluster have red color, other cluster has green, etc. I want those in one plot.

Comment: Welcome to DataScience! Your question needs to be a little more specific, focussed on a problem you are having. Have you tried doing it yourself already? Could you show us how far you got? Have a look for examples like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31137077/how-to-make-a-scatter-plot-for-clustering-in-python) and [all of these](https://nikkimarinsek.com/blog/7-ways-to-label-a-cluster-plot-python) - as well [the official matplotlib documentation](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/index.html) (a library for plotting).

Comment: Hi Dexter, I have looked into and tried other examples but not the one you advised. I will and if find solution will post here. Thank you for advising these.